# How do i write a script to guess a letter from a split up array?

Tags: javascript

This is kind of like wheel of fortune. I have split up a randomized array entry into individual letters, and I am trying to write a script that lets me be able to guess a letter from the array. full code below.

```js
var movietitles = ['Iron Man', ' Jaws', 'Avengers', 'Evil Dead', 'It', 'Transformers', 'Little Mermaid', 'Mulan', 'Scooby Doo', ];

const selection = movietitles[Math.floor(Math.random() * movietitles.length)];

let text = selection;

const game = text.split("");


for (var i = 0; i < game.length; i++) {

  var newEl = document.createElement('p');

  var newNode = document.createTextNode(game[i]);

  newEl.appendChild(newNode);

  document.body.appendChild(newEl);

  var tile = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

}

function guessLetter() {
  alert('Function called!');
  userInput.value = '';
}


var userInput = document.getElementById('entry');

userInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
  guessLetter(userInput.value);
});
```

```css
p {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.tile {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id=display></div>

<span>Please guess a letter or the whole title </span><input type=text id=entry>
```

I haven't tried anything because I am completely stumped by this

Comment: PSA: It's 2023 and it's time to learn about `let` and `const`.

Comment: Can you explain "completely stumped" in terms of a *technical problem* we can help solve?

Comment: The mixing of `var`, `const`, and `let` in various places suggests that you've picked bits of code from places around the web, to try and put this together? What is, or are, the problem(s) you're facing? Where are you specifically stuck? What's wrong with the code so far?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var movietitles = ['Iron Man', 'Jaws', 'Avengers', 'Evil Dead', 'It', 'Transformers', 'Little Mermaid', 'Mulan', 'Scooby Doo'];

const selection = movietitles[Math.floor(Math.random() * movietitles.length)];

let text = selection;

const game = text.split("");
var correctGuesses = new Array(game.length).fill(false);

for (var i = 0; i < game.length; i++) {
  var newEl = document.createElement('p');
  var newNode = document.createTextNode("_");
  newEl.appendChild(newNode);
  document.getElementById("display").appendChild(newEl);
}

function guessWord(guess) {
  var correctGuess = game.join('').toLowerCase() === guess.toLowerCase();
  if (correctGuess) {
    alert("Congratulations! You have correctly guessed the movie title!");
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect guess. Please try again.");
  }
}

var userInput = document.getElementById('entry');

userInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
  guessWord(userInput.value);
  userInput.value = "";
});
```

```css
p {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.tile {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id=display></div>

<span>Please guess a letter or the whole title </span><input type=text id=entry>
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code in your answer and expect people to understand what you've changed to solve the problem. Add an explanation as to what you have changed a long with links to documentation if necessary.